# Django Tagging - trouble with separated tags

Tags: django, django-tagging

I have got trouble with django tagging - filtering by tags consisting of several words does not work.
models

```
class MyWidget(models.Model):
    """Widget for tagging. It's damn bugged, so it need try except statement
    for be able to import in shell and work in general. Otherwise it's raiseing
    exception."""
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
try:
    tagging.register(MyWidget)
except tagging.AlreadyRegistered:
    pass
```

views

```
class PostsByTags(ListView):
    """View returns news filtered by tag."""
    template_name = 'news.djhtml'
    contect_object_name = 'news_list'
    def get_queryset(self):
        tags = unquote(self.kwargs['tag'])
        return TaggedItem.objects.get_by_model(News(), tags)
```

urls

```
url(r'^news/(?P<tag>[\w\s]*)/$',      views.PostsByTags.as_view(),
                                            name = 'tagged_news'),
```

If url looking something like that

> /news/separated%20tag/

the view class returns empty list. What the cause? How can I fix it?

Comment: try return TaggedItem.objects.get_by_model(News, tags). Notice News as opposed to News(). Also, unless you comma separate the list of Tags, it will return a single tag for every word. If you have a single tag "separated tag", just put a comma at the end "separated tag,"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thinks the query tag is being split into two (in tagging.utils.parse_tag_input).

get_by_model can also take a Tag item rather then a string, so try something like.

```
tag_object = Tag.objects.get(name=self.kwargs['tag'])
TaggedItem.objects.get_by_model(News(), tag_object)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have only to understand how this happened.

Answer (score 0):

What about formatting your url:

```
url(r'^news/((?P<tag>[^/]+))/$',      views.PostsByTags.as_view(),
                                            name = 'tagged_news'),
```